# Download drive video and store it in local device

Tags: java, android

I am unable to download google drive videos from gallery. When I select the video, `selectedvideouri` appends content like this:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/2/2/mediakey%3A%2FAF1QipPrn64nUjcIvpCbT_nnKuQHf0mdI6HPc7xMxI9t/ORIGINAL/NONE/418007042
```

and it throws exception

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: content
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: I want to download google photos or video which is saved in the device in the link "content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/2/2/mediakey%3A%2FAF1QipPrn64nUjcIvpCbT_nnKuQHf0mdI6HPc7xMxI9t/ORIGINAL/NONE/418007042 " to the local folder as "/storage/emulated/0/.../.../VID_20160705_104414.mp4" while doing this above exception was thrown

Answer (score 0):

Your selectedvideouri contains 
`content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/2/2/mediakey%3A%2FAF1QipPrn64nUjcIvpCbT_nnKuQHf0mdI6HPc7xMxI9t/ORIGINAL/NONE/418007042`
which is not the `URL` of the video.

You have to get the `URL` of the video and then pass it to downloader

And an `URL` will be of form `https://drive.google.com/file/video.mp4` or something similar. And it will point to a valid video file stored on google drive.

Comment: if it is already saved in device then you can just copy it to the location you want to save it to